# why do we put / and / in starting and ending of regular expressions in languages such as javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

for example regex for a 2 digit number in javascript would be`/^\d\d$/`.
So this reg ex contains `/` and `/` in starting and at the end.
So i wonder what's their purpose ?
Why can't we simply use `^\d\d$` ? 
Are they there to inform the interpreter that string is reg ex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just another way of saying `new RegExp(pattern)`. You can add modifiers to it by adding them after the second `/`:

```
var pattern = /pattern/modifiers;
```

Or

```
var pattern = new RegExp(pattern, modifiers);
```

Modifiers can be any of the following:

- `i` - case insensitive
- `m` - match on multiple lines
- `g` - find all matches

Answer (score 1):

Javascript allows you to simply put `/^\d\d$/` in code and it compiles, so we do not have to include quotes (2 less bytes) or an object constructor (over 13 bytes), plus it may be faster when it is precompiled using Javascript vs creating a `RegExp` object with a string.

Also after the second slash you can have more options like `g` and `i`.

Here is a test of performance.

http://jsperf.com/regexp-object-vs-regexp-inline

Comment: what would be the purpose of g and i ?
i'm new in reg ex field can you please elaborate this.

Comment: g = global, i = case insensitive

Comment: `g` means you want to find the pattern every where not just the first. `i` means you don't care about case (capital vs lowercase).

Comment: please take a look at this webpage. This is how I learned everything you need to know about regexp (basics). http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are effectively being used as markers around the string. Some languages let you use other characters in their place, like Perl. This is to make it easier to have "/" characters in the regex.

```
if (m#^/usr/spool/whatever/#) {
    do_something();
}
```